# render eats spaces after setViewValue in my custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create custom directive which only replace some symbols, it's work Almost fine, it's do a job but I can't use 'spacebar' in my input 'couse it's deletes and I can't understand why.

Here is my directive:

```js
 core.directive('comareplace', function () {

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                el.bind('keyup change', function () {
                    if (angular.isFunction(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.replace)) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.replace(',', ' '));
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

For example when you type into input this 'qwe,rt' it's replace it to 'qwe rt' but when you try to type this with spaces 'qwert     ' it's deletes spaces 'qwert'

Does anybody have an idea why? And how to correct it?

Comment: you may need check this, in default, value of ng-model will be trim:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AngularJS will trim input's content before binding it to the model.
You can opt-out from this default trimming by using the `ng-trim="false"` attribute.

> **ngTrim** : If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. This
>   parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which will
>   never trim the input.
>
> (default: true)
>
> [**Reference**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)

**Example**

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-trim="false" />
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhxL2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I didn't know it and it works. But can't press left arrow :) is there anything else special?

Comment: I guess it's the same trim theme but left arrow doesn't work